# How do I add CSS files?

Tags: 8, theming

Here is an example of my *.info file.

[image]

[image]

Why the page cannot load the CSS that I add myself?

Answer (score 6):

You Need to create a separate `*.libraries.yml` and declare it in your theme's `*.info.yml` file.

Note:

If your theme is named **"smart"**, then the file name should be `smart.libraries.yml`

**Attaching to all pages:**

To attach a library to all the pages on the site that use your theme, declare it in your theme's `*.info.yml` file.

```
name: smart
type: theme
core: 8.x
libraries:
  - smart/cuddly-slider
```

**Defining a library**

```
cuddly-slider:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/cuddly-slider.css: {}
```

Comment: How about if i want to resuse a css or js , suppose i have **cuddly-slider.css** in another module and do i need to include same in the current module's css folder ?

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 8, you need to define a "library" to add your custom CSS/JS

> The general steps for loading assets (CSS/JS) are:
>
> 1. Save the CSS or JS to a file.
> 2. Define a "library", which can contain both CSS and JS files.
> 3. "Attach" the library to a render array in a hook.
>
> But in the case of themes, there is an alternative to step 3: themes
>   can choose to load any number of asset libraries on all pages.

More details in the online documentation here: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets

Answer (score 0):

[Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets)

> In Drupal 8, stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) are loaded through the same system for modules (code) and themes, for everything: asset libraries. Asset libraries can contain one or more CSS assets, one or more JS assets and one or more JS settings.
>
> #### Defining a library
>
> To define one or more (asset) libraries, add a *.libraries.yml file to your module folder. (If your module is named fluffiness, then the file name should be fluffiness.libraries.yml). Each "library" in the file is an entry detailing CSS and JS files (assets), like this:

```
cuddly-slider:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/cuddly-slider.css: {}
  js:
    js/cuddly-slider.js: {}
```

In other words you need to create a library.

Comment: The OP is showing the .info.yml file of a theme, not a module.